# Memory retention of List<IEnumerable<T>> in foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq, garbage-collection, iqueryable

I have the following code:

```
public void ModelMinutesExtracter() {
        using (var abmContext = new ABMContext())
        {
            foreach (var period in abmContext.Periods.ToList())
            {
                var patternsPerPeriod =
                    abmContext.EnergyPatterns.Where(e => e.StartDate.Equals(period.Timestamp)).ToList();
                foreach (var pattern in patternsPerPeriod)
                {
                    // do stuff
                    abmContext.EnergyPatterns.AddOrUpdate(pattern);
                }
                abmContext.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Update period {period.Timestamp} (Id: {period.PeriodDimension_Id}).");
            }
        }
}
```

Amongst other stuff it produces a console line each time the outer loop finishes an iteration. The interval between the iterations increases significantly with the passing of running time, while I expect it to stay constant. I thought that the memory, the only maxed out performance category in this case, would remain constant as the garbace collector dumps each inner iteration (`pattern`), which is what I read in answers to related/similar StackOverflow questions.

Is there a way to improve the performance of such iterations?

Comment: Have you noticed a steady increase in memory consumption? You're creating a lot of in-memory lists. You don't need that. You could also try to move the `abmContext.SaveChanges()` to the end, so update all in one batch.

Comment: Your linq-to-sql context keeps everything you load in memory (to support `SaveChanges`).

Comment: `the garbace collector dumps each inner iteration` is false. GC free memory whenever it decides to do. In your case it may decide that freeing memory at the end of the loop wouldn't have good impacts on performance

Comment: @TimSchmelter the memory rapidly increases to max alotted. I have moved the `SaveChanges()` to outside the loops and removed `ToList()` from linq queries. The performance has increased significantly